# Is there an equivalent for DataFrame.iteritems() that does not include the name?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have some legacy code with multiple instances like this...

```
result = function(df['a'], df['b'], df['z'])
```

The function accepts `*args` so I wondered if I could "tidy" the code by doing the following...

```
result = function(df[['a','b','z']].iteritems())
```

But `iteritems()` returns a list of `(name, Series)` pairs, so it doesn't work.

Is there a "tidy" way to get access to the list of `Series` only?  *(no pairs, no `name`)*

*(Changing the function is not ideal; it's designed to work with Scalars and Arrays, and as a Series is ArrayLike they work too.  So I just would "like" a list of the Series on their own...)*

My best attempt is just to get the Series as Arrays instead, but I "dis-like" it due to multiple instances of boiler-plate code, it feels like there "should" be a direct way to iterate on the Series?

```
result = function(*(df[['a','b','z']].to_numpy().T))
```

Comment: `function(*[df[i] for i in df[["a","b","z"]]])`?

Comment: `func(*df.loc[:,['A','B','D']].values.T.tolist())?`  Why do you think the original is *un-tidy*?

Comment: @wwii - Perhaps "tidy" is a poor choice of words. I reworked the functions so that they work with scalars or arrays, and so that they work in any number of dimensions. (Usually three, sometimes two, but also sometimes four). So, I wanted a way of passing around whole DataFrames containing the n dimensions being worked in.  With numpy arrays that's possible; `*array_of_arrays`. With DataFrames I had to revert to explicitly listing the n dimensions, so losing generality.  This means that `*[df[i] for i in df]` may currently be the closest to what I want. But it's still not exactly "terse".

Comment: @HenryYik I'll pay you 10 or 25 points to copy that in to an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping through a `Dataframe` returns a list of column names, so you can use list comprehension:

```
function(*[df[i] for i in df[["a","b","z"]]])
```